# Can Nokogiri extract metadata and combine with main record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, nokogiri, healthkit

200,000 line XML and the data of interest looks like the following (extraneous info removed). There are other Records and nodes not of interest

```
<Record type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifier" startDate="2021-10-05 09:43:40 -0800" value="130">
  <MetadataEntry key="HKTimeZone" value="America/Los_Angeles"/>
  other MetadatEntries
</Record>
```

The following Nokogiri grabs only the top lines of each `Record` to `records`

```
document = File.open(path) { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }
records = document.xpath("//Record[contains(@type,'HKQuantityTypeIdentifier')]").map(&:to_h)
```

with a typical line looking like:

```
{"type"=>"HKQuantityTypeIdentifier", "startDate"=>"2014-04-02 09:48:00 -0800", "value"=>"110"}
```

I want to add the `HKTimeZone` MetadataEntry to the hash (and then I can extract the information together later)

```
{"type"=>"HKQuantityTypeIdentifier", "startDate"=>"2014-04-02 09:48:00 -0800", "value"=>"110", timeZone="America/Los_Angeles"}
```

or whatever the value was for `HKTimeZone`. The `startDate`, `value` and `timeZone` are grabbed line by line and added to the database along with other data.

Can Nokogiri do this? Or any other suggestions? Can't say as I understand Nokogiri. Most of the code is by someone other than me. Thank you.

Or can Nokogiri, just add the entire `Record` to `record` and then parse it later? In other words Nogogiri gathers each Record with `type="HKQuantityTypeIdentifier"` and parse afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably more elegant solutions, but this should work:

```rb
doc.xpath("//Record[contains(@type,'HKQuantityTypeIdentifier')]").map do |node|
  # Set temporary variable with record node cast to hash
  hsh = node.to_h
  # Add 'timeZone' key to temporary variable, with the @value of the first child node Metadata[@key='HKTimeZone']
  hsh["timeZone"] = node.xpath("MetadataEntry[@key='HKTimeZone']/@value").text
  # Return temporary variable for collection
  hsh
end
```